# Lock Registry Key from Windows Itself

Tags: windows, permissions, registry

I'm trying to lock out a Registry from being altered by the System. When Windows 10 Updates push, it set 90% of out registry Hive data back to Factory Default. Which get annoying to fix after patching. The issue is the system is creating subkeys under certain keys that are wrecking configs. I've tried locking out the ability to write subkeys from the system with the the following:

```
//Sample Key : HKLM\Key1\Key2 (Key1 is the Key in question)
• Took Ownership (owner = localhost\administrators)
• Disabled Inheritance

//Security Config (Allow)
ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES = Read
CREATOR OWNER = Special
SYSTEM = Read
ADMINISTRATORS = Read
USERS = Read

• All Subkeys are mirrored through the GUI

//Notes
I've done this with several different attempts, but after patching is complete, the Windows is back to factory. I noticed TrustedInstaller is not on the list, but this should deny that account correct?

Thanks in advance for any help. :)
```

Comment: Are you talking about regular updates, or new builds of Windows 10?

Comment: I'm not sure... I think its the security updates. ie Security update for Windows 1151.